# how to use method canDeserialize ObjectMapper class from jackson API?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to use  method  canDeserialize, because at moment  deserialization i want to get  type class for apply at custom deserialization, as about next example :

```
    public T deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws SerializationException {
       bolean isAccount = this.objectMapper.canDeserialize(??????).
           T t = null;

          if(isAccount)
            t = (T)this.objectMapper.readValue(bytes,Account.class);

          else 
            t = (T) this.objectMapper.readValue(bytes, 0, bytes.length, new TypeReference<Object>(){});

         return t;
    }
```

In this case Account class have annotation *@JsonDeserialize* for a custom deserialization .

Comment: What do you want to do? What array of bytes represents? Is this a String? Could you provide more info about the context and problem? Could you show, how you invoke this "deserialize" method?

Comment: Yea, your going to need to pass a Class as one of the parameters to the method. I would recommend also providing an override that takes a Type. Note that you do not need to handle custom deserialization manually, the Jackson runtime will detect classes with `@JsonDeserialize` and handle them automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To directly answer your question, this is how you use the `canDeserialize` method:

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.canDeserialize(mapper.constructType(Bean.class));
```

Where `Bean` is the name of your Java class to be checked.

But ***wait***, you are trying to solve the wrong problem. You are struggling with the logic for your method because it has not been designed properly. You are *really* asking  too much of the Java runtime (and Jackson library), by trying to make them infer all the required information about the type to be instantiated (based on the parameterized return). To solve this you should include the class representing the type to be deserialized as a parameter to the method, greatly simplifying the logic:

```
public <T> T deserialize(byte[] bytes, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException,
      JsonProcessingException {
   return new ObjectMapper().readValue(bytes, clazz);
}
```

At this point you have probably realized that the method above provides no additional functionality over just calling `ObjectMapper.readValue` directly, so ... **just do that**! No need to define custom methods, just use `ObjectMapper` and you are good to go. Keep in mind that you do not need to do anything explicit to trigger custom deserialization of classes. The Jackson runtime automatically detects when a class has a custom deserializer and invokes it.